# Does await create another thread internally before shifting to the same thread as the caller (for UI application)

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

What I know about async/await is that when the task completes, the continuation is run on the same context when the await was called, which would, in my case, be the UI thread.
But my question is, does it create a new thread (internally) after IO is complete and before moving to the same UI thread.

I am sharing a piece of code. If I click on this button once, It shows that available thread is 1023 before executing await, but after that, available threads dropped to 1022. Although When I check the thread id, it is the same as UI thread.

```
    private async void button1_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x, y;
        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out x, out y);
        textBox1.Text = x.ToString()+"..."+y.ToString();
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out x, out y);
        textBox1.Text = x.ToString() + "..." + y.ToString();
    }
```

But interestingly, next time when I click on this button, number of available threads remains 1023 (before and after await).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But my question is, does it create a new thread (internally) after IO is complete and before moving to the same UI thread.

Other threads may be temporarily used, but you don't need to worry about that.

In particular, I/O on .NET generally goes through an I/O completion port that is part of the thread pool. I/O threads are automatically added and removed as necessary. Fairly often, the I/O has some additional work to do before it actually is ready to return to your code (e.g., parsing HTTP response headers), so a *lot* of the BCL I/O code will actually use the I/O thread just to queue work to the thread pool. So a thread pool worker thread is often used (briefly) by I/O code.

Also, in this particular example, I believe there's a separate timer thread as well, that coalesces system timers. Naturally, this is an implementation detail and subject to change.

So, in summary, other threads may be created/destroyed/temporarily used, but you don't have to worry about it. They're all managed by the BCL or .NET runtime in a very efficient manner, striking a balance between reusing threads (minimizing churn) and minimizing resource use (especially memory).

Comment: Thanks Stephen for the answer ! One more thing. If this "async method" is waited (and not awaited), I assume .net still goes through I/O completion port and one of the I/O temporary thread is transit to the thread that calling method wait for.

Comment: @Pragmatic: Yes, it would still go through the same path. It would *have* to, because the method being called has no idea whether you're going to `await` or `Wait` it in the future. However, blocking on asynchronous code is an anti-pattern and should definitely be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, This was really helpful. Sometimes we have to follow this anti pattern. For ex, when we want to execute multiple IO operations, we call multiple Async API and then WaitAll() on them (again, if calling method cannot be made async). This is much better than creating explicit tasks and then calling API's sync version.

Comment: @Pragmatic: I just suggest that you re-evaluate "calling method cannot be made async". I hear that a lot, but it's only **true** maybe 2-3% of the time. Usually it's a case of "I don't want to do it because it's haaaard..."

Comment: Thanks again for your response. We are building a background job that read message from a queue (Azure service bus). We have an event handler that listens to message arrived. As soon as it arrives, we execute this piece of code. We need to wait till the time event handler is executed, and awaiting a eventhandler is not possible.

Comment: Please provide your thoughts on "we call multiple Async API and then WaitAll() on them (again, if calling method cannot be made async). This is much better than creating explicit tasks and then calling API's sync version and WaitAll()?"

Comment: @Pragmatic: It would be better to block a single thread than multiple threads. That said, most background job processors these days support `async` out of the box.

Comment: I am sorry but I did not understand "it would be better to block a single thread than multiple"? I guess, in calling multiple Async methods and WaitAll(), system wait for multiple threads (although these threads are temporary). And Yes, I cound async Job Processors as well.

Comment: @Pragmatic: I mean `WaitAll` only blocks one thread; doing a `Parallel` or multiple threads calling sync versions would block multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you meant it dropped to 1022.

In general I think it depends on the async call being made. Disk and network calls will come back on a thread from the I/O completion thread pool. It appears that `Task.Delay` returns on a regular worker thread.

You can change the line to `await Task.Delay(5000).ConfigureAwait(false);` , set a breakpoint after it and check the Threads window to see this directly.

It will complete on a worker thread no matter where you call it from. `await` doesn't communicate the calling context to the function implementing the async operation; it only adds the extra step of returning to the UI thread when it's done.

I wouldn't read too much into tracking the exact number here; the CLR has its own algorithms that manage the thread pool size and those can change from release to release. And I wouldn't stress about it using a different thread there: in a normal app it will simply re-use an existing thread from the pool and the operation will be very fast.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. Yes thread count dropped to 1022. I made this correction.

Comment: This is not about stressing on the count. I just want to understand how it works. let me take another use case. When multiple async calls are made and then awaited using Task.Whenall(), How many threads are created internally. As per my understanding, separate threads for all such calls (after IO is done). That might happen for a short duration. And then all these threads will be transitioned to UI thread.

Comment: Each task is going to return on a threadpool thread. Usually these do not need to be created, just borrowed. As for Task.WhenAll, I did a bit of testing and I think it returns on the thread of the last task that completes.